# Display of selected checkboxes not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox, display

I would like to display the names of the selected checkboxes when I click Submit.

For example:

- If no checkbox is checked display should be "Please select a hobby".
- If painting is checked display "#painting"
- If painting and reading is checked display "#reading#painting"

The below given code is not working.

```js
function displayHobbies(){
let HobbiesInput=[document.getElementById('dancing'),
document.getElementById('reading'),
document.getElementById('painting')];
var HobbiesError="";
for(var i=0;i<HobbiesInput.length;i++)
{
 if (HobbiesInput[i].checked==false)
 {
            HobbiesError="Please select a hobby";
 } 
 else
 {
     HobbiesError +="#"+HobbiesInput[i].name;
 }
}
document.getElementById('hobbies_display').innerHTML=HobbiesError;
}
```

```html
<form name= "myform" onclick="displayHobbies()">

Hobby <input type="checkbox" id="dancing" name="dancing">
     <label for="dancing">Dancing</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="reading" name="reading">
     <label for="reading">Reading</label>
     <input type="checkbox" id="painting" name="painting">      
     <label for="painting">Painting</label>
<button type="button" id="hobby_submit">Submit</button>
</form>
Hobbies:<label id="hobbies_display"></label>
```

Comment: Why is there an onclick on the form tag? Don't you want submit?

Comment: First, you should clear out the `hobbies_display` label every time something is clicked. Second, your for loop doesn't check to see if they're _all_ unchecked to display that message, it checks if _any_ are unchecked. So if the first two are checked, but the last one isn't, it'll look at that last one, see that it's unchecked, and then set the message to say that nothing is checked.

Comment: @epascarello its supposed to be onclick...I don't want to submit the form

Comment: but that is any click inside of the form, not clicking on the button. So submit the form and preventDefault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, if there is an unchecked box, the code will add the "Please select a hobby" message.

Instead, check that at the end, and this will work:

```js
function displayHobbies() {
  let HobbiesInput = [
    document.getElementById('dancing'),
    document.getElementById('reading'),
    document.getElementById('painting')
  ];
  var HobbiesError = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < HobbiesInput.length; i++) {
    if (HobbiesInput[i].checked) {
      HobbiesError += "#" + HobbiesInput[i].name;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('hobbies_display').innerHTML = HobbiesError || "Please select a hobby";
}
```

```html
<form name="myform" onclick="displayHobbies()">

  Hobby <input type="checkbox" id="dancing" name="dancing">
  <label for="dancing">Dancing</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="reading" name="reading">
  <label for="reading">Reading</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="painting" name="painting">
  <label for="painting">Painting</label>
  <button type="button" id="hobby_submit">Submit</button>
</form>
Hobbies:<label id="hobbies_display"></label>
```

Comment: @MegCullen You can accept an answer (by the checkmark), to help the others find better answers

Answer (score 1):

Here is something a little bit more clean:

```
function displayHobbies() {

  let HobbiesInput = [
      document.getElementById('dancing'),
      document.getElementById('reading'),
      document.getElementById('painting')
  ];

  // flag if no hobby is checked
  var noHobbiesChecked = true;

  // reset display area
  document.getElementById('hobbies_display').innerHTML = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < HobbiesInput.length; i++) {

    if (HobbiesInput[i].checked === true)   {
      // add hobby to display area
      document.getElementById('hobbies_display').innerHTML += "#"+HobbiesInput[i].name;
      // turn off the flag since we have at least one hobby checked
      noHobbiesChecked = false; 
    }

  }

  if (noHobbiesChecked === true) {
    // show error
    document.getElementById('hobbies_display').innerHTML = "Please select a hobby";
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function displayHobbies() {
let HobbiesInput=[document.getElementById('dancing'),
                  document.getElementById('reading'),
                  document.getElementById('painting')];
var HobbiesError="";

for(var i=0;i<HobbiesInput.length;i++)
{
 if (HobbiesInput[i].checked) {
         HobbiesError +="#"+HobbiesInput[i].name;
 }
}

if (!HobbiesError) {
    HobbiesError="Please select a hobby";
}

document.getElementById('hobbies_display').innerHTML = HobbiesError;
}
```

```html
<form name= "myform" onsubmit="displayHobbies(); return false;">

Hobby <input type="checkbox" id="dancing" name="dancing">
     <label for="dancing">Dancing</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="reading" name="reading">
     <label for="reading">Reading</label>
     <input type="checkbox" id="painting" name="painting">      
     <label for="painting">Painting</label>
<button type="submit" id="hobby_submit">Submit</button>
</form>
Hobbies:<label id="hobbies_display"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet for doing this. We are attaching a listener to a form (not to an every input). Then we look if the thing we clicked is actually an input type `checkbox`. Then if it `checked` we push it's value to the array we want to display on top, if `not checked` we are removing from this array. Then we select a element we want to render our list in, and render. Hope it helps.

```js
let values = [];
const form = document.getElementById('form')
form.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (!e.target.type === 'checkbox') return;
  const value = e.target.value;
  const checked = e.target.checked;
  if (checked) {
    values.push(value)
  } else {
    const newValues = values.filter(v => v !== value);
    values = newValues;
  }
  const valuesList = document.getElementById('valuesList')
  valuesList.innerHTML = values.map(m => `#${m}`).join('')
})
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <div id="valuesList"></div>
  <div>
    I have a bike
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
  </div>
  <div>
    I have a car
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="Car">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!! :)